# Profile not being set in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have following profiles in my parent pom

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <properties>
            <env>uat</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>tst</id>
        <properties>
            <env>tst</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prd</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prd</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have created application-uat.properties and application-dev.properties .
I have

> app.name=app.name= This is dev profile
>   and 
>   app.name=app.name= This is uat profil

in respective applictaion properties.

In eclipse i chose Maven profile as uat.

While launching the spring boot profile i get the below message

> No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'myBean': Injection of autowired dependencies
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
>   not resolve placeholder 'app.name' in value "${app.name}"

How can i resolve it?

Comment: Do you really have app.name=app.name= in the properties?

Comment: These are *Maven* profiles, which are used at build time. You haven't shown anywhere that you're connecting that to *Spring* profiles, which are used at runtime.

Comment: @chrylis "You haven't shown anywhere that you're connecting that to Spring profiles" .I havent done any configuration for that.How can i do it?

Yes there is app.name in both the properties file

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder